# Magento 2 - what does the require means in composer json?

Tags: magento2

```
"require": {
        "segmentio/analytics-php": "^1.5",
    }
```

This code is there in composer json, when i have composer update the segmentio lib version changed from 1.5 to 1.7 not sure why.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` means, the package you are installing require this package: please check [link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require)

The `^` in module version represent version number up to it can be update.

For example ^1.5 is equivalent to >=1.5 <2.0.0

For more information see [link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you please answer if their any possibility to override library php file in module such as
/Magento2/vendor/segmentio/analytics-php/lib/Segment/QueueConsumer.php ?

Comment: welcome @devhs. it is a third party lib not a Magento 2 standard module.I not aware about overriding third party lib. I will check and try it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, i need to check if it can be override or not